# 6th Degree Polynomial and Chebyshev minmax

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, chebyshev-polynomials, euler-maclaurin

I have to find the 6th degree polynomial for the function $f(x)=xe^x$. After which the use of the Chebyshev min-max approach I have to use the list grade polynomial approach with respect to the fault 0.01 at [-1,1].

I don't think that I can use Taylor or Maclaurin.
Any idea?

Comment: You have to determine the exact minimax polynomial of degree 6 for the function $f(x)=xe^x$ on $[-1,1]$, and then, the minimax polynomial of least degree giving a maximal error of $0.01$ on that interval, did I get that right? There's [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm), of course, but if you have to do that by hand, it's not funny. It's an iterative procedure, and you'd have to solve a linear system ($8\times8$) in every step (among other things).

Comment: @ProfessorVector First I have to find the 6th grade, but I don't see any certain point. Then I use the Chebyshev min-max approach with tolerance 0.01 at the space [-1,1]. The second procedure aims to give me the list grade polynomial. I don't want to do it by hand. I am using MATLAB.